# What design pattern might help us implement a simple stream filter (or interpreter)?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, stream, compiler-construction, interpreter

This is kind of a "white-board" question instead a "keyboard" question as it is not language-specific.

I often have a stream of characters which must be translated from one "*language*" to another...

**EXAMPLE ONE: UPS & DOWNS**

```non
+---------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| INPUT STREAM  | (-1, 0) | (0, 1) | (0, 1)  | (0, 1) | (0, -1) | (0, 1)  | (0, 1)  |
+---------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| OUTPUT STREAM | "left"  | "up"   | "right" | "up"   | "down"  | "right" | "right" |
+---------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**EXAMPLE TWO: Toggling Between Cases**

You can force stream output to be pure lower-case or pure upper-case and use a "`$`" character to toggle between different modes:

```py
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| INPUT:  | "ApPleS" |     "$"     | "BaNaNaS" |      "$"       | "BLACKberries" |      "$"      | "BlUeBeRrIeS" |     "$"      | "CaNtAlOuPe" |
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| OUTPUT: | "APPLES" | toggle mode | "bananas" | "BLACKBERRIES" | toggle mode    | "blueberries" | toggle mode   | toggle mode  | "CANTALOUPE" |
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Suppose that you had a class named `CharEater` which eats elements of a stream and sends new (translated) elements to another stream.

Exactly what characters the `CharEater` outputs should vary depending on what "***mode***" the stream filter is in.

Maybe are only a handful of *modes* (4 to 7 ***modes***) that the class can be in.

I usually write very ugly code which amounts to a bunch of:

- nested loops
- if-else clauses
- boolean flags.

For some reason, my boolean flags usually have names beginning with the word "`is`" or "`has`", such as:

- "`is_valid`"
- "`is_digit`"
- "`is_red`".
- "`is_blue`".
- "`has_hit_rock_bottom`".

An example of some ugly code is shown below:

```py
import io

def eat_the_string(chars:str):
    """
    The implementation here is ugly

    However...
        we accept a string as input

        we convert letters to upper case or lower case

        A dollar sign ($) is used to toggle between upper-case mode
        and lower-case mode.

    EXAMPLE
        INPUT:
            "ApPleS $ BaNaNaS $ BLACKberries $ BlUeBeRrIeS $ CaNtAlOuPe"
        OUTPUT:
            "APPLES  bananas  BLACKBERRIES  blueberries  CANTALOUPE"
    """
    strm = io.StringIO() # a string stream
    is_lowercase = False
    for ch in chars:
        if ch == "$":
            is_lowercase = not is_lowercase
        else:
            if is_lowercase:
                print(
                    ch.lower(),
                    file=strm, sep = "", end = ""
                )
            else: # in uppercase mode
                print(
                    ch.upper(),
                    file=strm, sep="", end=""
                )
    return strm.getvalue()
```

I am seeking a more elegant solution.

A bunch of nested loops with a handful of boolean flags is not great for many reasons.

Two drawbacks are:

- the mess of boolean flags and test conditions is difficult for human beings to read and understand
- a lot of the test-conditions are redundant. I sometimes an if statement for `is_first_iteration == True` even though it is guaranteed that `is_first_iteration` will be False after the first loop iteration.

What is an example of a better design pattern (or approach) for implementing a stream filter whose output changes based on what **mode** the stream filter is in? We probably do not need a full-blown general-purpose parser and interpreter, but that is one option.

Below is one attempt to re-factor the mess of nested-loops with boolean flags. Feel free to steer me in a different direction.

```py
# import tools for abstract base classes
import io
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class PacAbstract(ABC):
    # This is an abstract base class

    @abstractmethod
    def process_a_char(this, ch: str):
        """
            Input paramater `old_ch` is a char, such as the letter "A"
        """
        pass  # `pass` is no_op().... no_operation()... do nothing.


class PacModeLowercase(PacAbstract):
    """
        `PacModeLowercase` converts
        string characters into lower-case letters
    """

    def process_a_char(this: PacAbstract, ch: str):
        """
            Input parameter `old_ch` is a char, such as the letter "A"
        """
        return ch.lower()


class PacModeUppercase(PacAbstract):
    """
         This class represents a **mode**
         for an `PacMan` to be in.

        `PacModeUppercase` converts
        string characters into upper-case letters
    """

    def process_a_char(this: PacAbstract, ch: str):
        # Input paramter `old_ch` is a string, such as "hello world"
        return ch.upper()


class PacMan(PacAbstract):
    PacModeUppercase = PacModeUppercase
    PacModeLowercase = PacModeLowercase
    # Like the videogame character named "pacman,"
    # a `PacMan` eats things.
    #
    # a PacMan has a pointer (or reference) to a PacMode
    # `PacMode` represents the **mode** which the PacMan is in
    #
    # The mode determines what PacMan outputs.

    def __init__(this: PacAbstract, *, mode: str = "lower"):
        # __init__ is sort of like a class constructor.
        #
        # However, the true constructor is type.__call__()
        #
        # In other languages,
        # `__call__()` is sometimes known as ``
        #
        # All of the following are equvilant:
        #    instance = PacMan(1, 2, 3)
        #    instance = type.__call__(PacMan, 1, 2, 3)

        # Error checking. make sure mode is string-like
        mode = "".join(str(ch) for ch in mode)

        # Get modified copy with trimmed leading and traiPacAbstract white space
        mode = mode.strip()

        # Get modified copy with uppercase letters
        # converted to lowercase letters
        mode = mode.lower()

        if mode == "lower":
            this._pac_mode = type(this).PacModeLowercase()
        else:
            this._pac_mode = type(this).PacModeUppercase()

    def process_a_char(this: PacAbstract, ch: str):
        """
            Input paramter `old_ch` is a string, such as "hello world"
        """
        return this._pac_mode.process_a_char(ch)


pacman = PacMan()

strm = io.StringIO()
inputs = "ApPleS $ BaNaNaS $ BLACKberries $ BlUeBeRrIeS $ CaNtAlOuPe"
for old_ch in inputs:
    new_ch = pacman.process_a_char(old_ch)
    print(new_ch, file=strm, sep="", end="")

print(strm.getvalue())
# output is "apples $ bananas $ blackberries $ blueberries $ cantaloupe"
```

Anyway.... what is the name of a design pattern such that the data coming out of a stream filter varies
depending on what "***mode***" the stream filter is in?

Below is code written to convert camel-case to lower-case letters and under-scores.

The code is written in the anti-pattern of nested loops, boolean flags, and buffers:

```py
def camel_to_underscore(chars:str):
    """
    The implementation here is an anti-pattern 

    The code is hideous mess of nested-loops, boolean
    flags, test-conditions, and string buffers. 

    EXAMPLE A:
        INPUT:  "getUserInput()"
        OUTPUT: "get_user_input()
        
    EXAMPLE B:
        INPUTS: 
                RedDeliciousApples
                GrannySmithApples
                ConcordGrapes
                GreenGrapes
        Outputs:
                red_delicious_apples
                granny_smith_apples
                concord_grapes
                green_grapes
    """
    chars = "".join(str(ch) for ch in chars)
    it = iter(chars)
    buffer = []
    buffer.append(next(it).lower())
    for ch in it:
        low_ch = ch.lower()
        if low_ch != ch:
            buffer.append("_")
        buffer.append(low_ch)
    return "".join(buffer)
```

If you do not have the name of a design pattern, do you have some pseudo-code different from the nest-loops with boolean flags? Maybe some sort of class object whose method outputs change depending on what "**mode**" the class is in?

**EXAMPLE THREE: Removing Consecutive Duplicates**

An example of a more complicated application might be to delete repeated sub-strings:

- we read a string from left to right
- if the same sub-string repeats itself (`"Echo Echo Echo Echo"`) then we delete the redundant copies.
- we allow a single character to repeat up to 2 times, but no other string may repeat.

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| "Misssssssssissssssssippppppppppi" | "Mississippi" |
| "apple apple apple apple" | "apple" |
| "orange orange orange orange orange" | "orange" |
| "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" | "\n\n" |

Comment: The best design pattern here is "Coroutine", by the way, but not all languages have convenient implementations. In Python or EcmaScript, you can use generators for an elegant solution. But I don't think I'd venture a non-language-specific answer.

Comment: Finally, you need to more precisely define whitespace handling in your "removing duplicates" example. Or, more generally, clarify what happens when the tail of the repetition is (or starts with) a prefix of the repeated pattern. In general, the hardest part of parsing problems is coming up with a precise description of the input; that's precisely the problem which formal grammars address (but not always successfully, because not all input formats are context-free).

Comment: @rici You are correct. I said that any two characters could be repeated in a row. As such the output should be two line-feeds (`\n\n`) instead of `\n` I will edit the question to show two line-feeds instead of onel

Comment: @rici you are right about the white space. The string "apple " with a space at the end is different than the string "apple" with no space at the end. I might edit the question in order to clarify what to do about white space characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, this is a place where Fluent interface pattern can be used. As [wiki says about Fluent interface pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

> In software engineering, a fluent interface is an object-oriented API
> whose design relies extensively on method chaining. Its goal is to
> increase code legibility by creating a domain-specific language (DSL).
> The term was coined in 2005 by Eric Evans and Martin Fowler

I do not know Python, but let me show an example via C#.

You can create `Pipe` class:

```
class Pipe
{
    string[] _stream;

    public Pipe(string[] stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
    }

    public List<string> ConvertedStream { get; } = new List<string>();

    public Pipe ToLowerCase()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _stream.Length; i++)
        {
            // this complicated logic should be moved 
            // to another class. This code snippet is
            // just for demo purpose
            if (_stream[i] != "$")
                _stream[i] = _stream[i].ToLower();
            else
                _stream[i] = "toggle mode";
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Pipe ToUnique()
    {
        
        // this complicated logic should be moved to another class. This 
        // code snippet is just for demo purpose
        for (int i = 0; i < _stream.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_stream[i] == "Misssssssssissssssssippppppppppi")
                _stream[i] = "Mississippi";
            else if (_stream[i] == "apple apple apple apple")
                _stream[i] = "apple";
            else if (_stream[i] == "orange orange orange orange orange")
                _stream[i] = "orange";
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

And code can be run like this:

```
string[] words = 
{
    "Misssssssssissssssssippppppppppi",
    "apple apple apple apple",
    "orange orange orange orange orange",
    "$"
};

Pipe pipe = new Pipe(words);
pipe.ToUnique()
    .ToLowerCase();
```

So the `words` array would look like this after applying your filters such as `ToUnique` and `ToLowerCase`:

```
"mississippi"   
"apple" 
"orange"    
"toggle mode"
```

Comment: C# is good. It does not matter to me what language the answer is in so long as the language is not too esoteric. Most object oriented design patterns can be implemented in C#, Java, C++, python, etc...

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)